# BSTSet Implementation of methods contains(T value) and add(T value) using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, set, binary-search-tree, abstract-data-type

```
package csci152.impl;

import csci152.adt.Set;
import csci152_classes.TreeNode;

public class BSTSet<T extends Comparable> implements Set<T> {

    private TreeNode<T> root;
    private int size;
    public BSTSet(){
        root = null;
        size = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void add(T value) {
        if(!contains(value)){
           addHelper(value, root); 
        }
    }      

    private void addHelper(T value, TreeNode<T> n){
        if(n ==null){
            if(size ==0){
                root = new TreeNode<T>(value);
            }else{           
            **n = new TreeNode<T>(value);**}
            size++;

            return;
        }
        if(value.compareTo(n.getValue())>0){
            addHelper(value, n.getRight());
        }else if(value.compareTo(n.getValue())<0){
            addHelper(value,n.getLeft());
        }            
    }  




    @Override
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        return containsHelper(value, root);

    }

    private boolean containsHelper(T value, TreeNode<T> node){
             if(node ==null){
            return false;
        }
        if(value.compareTo(node.getValue())>0){
            return containsHelper(value, node.getRight());
        }else if(value.compareTo(node.getValue())<0){
            return containsHelper(value,node.getLeft());
        }return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(T value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public T removeAny() throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
        root = null;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return toStringHelper(root);
    }

    private String toStringHelper(TreeNode<T> node){
        if(node == null){
            return "";
        }
        return toStringHelper(node.getLeft()) +
                node.getValue() +
                toStringHelper(node.getRight());
    }

}
```

The code underlined (n = new TreeNode(value);) does not properly work. So when I run code, size is incremented, but root is kept null and new TreeNode is not created. Why is this? Where is my mistake? Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

First you should debug your program, go over it step by step and check every variable. that is a very important exercise.

But to answer your question the first time root is null, then you send it as n, so n is null as well, then you initialize null with TreeNode, it's still null.